# How to write a PHPUnit test for a SOAP server?

Tags: testing, soap, phpunit

UPD. Sorry, guys.
I have an application that acts as a SOAP server, how do I write a PHPUnit test to test it?

Comment: To test the SOAP server, you just need to write something that consumes it. There's a lot of overhead that makes doing this in SOAP time consuming, but you probably already have an application that consumes those services from which you can extract enough to make a small test app.

Comment: I want to use PHPUnit for this, but i don't know how i can do it

Answer (score 2):

SOAP extension is reading data from PHP input stream. You just provide your own data there and create some integration/unit tests for your API.

Take a look at the signature of `SoapServer::handle()` method. It takes as an argument a string which is a request itself. This parameter is optional and if you don't pass anything in, PHP will just read the data itself. But you can simply override it.

I used streams to do it. First you wrap the SoapServer with your own class like this:

```
class MyServer
{
    /** \SoapServer */
    private $soapServer;

    public function __construct(\SoapServer $soapServer)
    {
        $this->soapServer = $soapServer;
    }

    public function handle(Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface $inputStream): void
    {
        $this->soapServer->handle($inputStream->getContent());
    }
}
```

Now you are ready to mock the request.

In your test you can do:

```
class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testMyRequest(): void
    {
        $mySoapServer = $this->createMySoapServer();
        $request = $this->createRequest();

        $mySoapServer->handle($request);
    }

    private function createRequest(): StreamInterface
    {
        $requestString = '<soap:Envelope></soap:Envelope>';

        $fh = fopen('php://temp', 'rw');
        fwrite($fh, $requestString);
        fseek($fh, SEEK_SET);

        return new Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface\Stream($fh);
    }

    private function createMySoapServer(): MyServer
    {
        return new MyServer(new \SoapServer());
    }
}
```

One thing to keep in mind - this test will generate output. You may want to test this output or ignore it. Depends on your use case.

Another side note. What you are asking for has really nothing to do with PHPUnit. It just a matter of designing your SOAP server correctly.

If you are wondering how to set up the stream when you have a live request, this is really simple:

```
$server->handle(new Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface\Stream(fopen('php://input', 'r+')));
```

Comment: Thx, for your answer. But i don't understand what does it mean $mySoapServer = $this->createMySoapServer();   ? Where is the method which creating SoapServer? Can you explain it? Thx.

Comment: Just edited the answer with a more complete example.

Comment: I'm trying exactly that but SoapServer::handle() seems to try to send HTTP headers which causes an `headers already sent` issue.

Comment: You should mock any actual (HTTP) communication. Using an abstraction like the PSR HTTP messages is the best option. This will however require implementation that has the soap server composited rather than **extended**. If you call `SoapServer::handle()`, you rely on the php internal implementation. However, your unit test should focus on the actual response it builds. The actual http communication is a detail which can only be tested properly with integration tests.